# How can I Export Warnings generated by HeidiSQL

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to do a bulk data upload into a MariaDB database.  The data file has over 3M records.  When the SQL runs the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement, I get over 9600 warnings where there were problems when the data was inserted.  In order to chase down why there were problems, I need to get the row numbers of each record where an error was encountered so I can filter the source file and examine the problem columns.

I'm using HeidiSQL as my front-end, and there doesn't appear to be a way to export the list of warnings.  I tried to direct the output of the `SHOW WARNINGS` statement to an external file like you would a query, but that doesn't work (probably because the warnings are not persistent data like data in a table would be).

Does anyone know how I can save the list of Warnings to an external file?

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS` _must_ be executed before any other command.  Possibly HeidiSQL inserted something that would normally be harmless.

Comment: It actually prompts you when there are warnings and HeidiSQL will show them in a separate tab in the GUI.  It's just that when the warnings are displayed, only a small number of the messages can be seen and they're not in a format that allows it to be exported.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn how to use the commandline "mysql" tool.  Then perform the `LOAD` and `SHOW` there.

**Example**

`tee filename` can be invoked from the CLI *without* losing the `WARNINGs`:

```
CREATE TABLE dtts (
    ... just_date DATE ... );

mysql> INSERT INTO dtts (just_date) VALUES (NOW());
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> tee /tmp/mtee
Logging to file '/tmp/mtee'
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                        |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'just_date' at row 1 |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
rj$ ls -l /tmp/mtee
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rj rj 389 Dec  7 14:05 /tmp/mtee
rj$ cat /tmp/mtee
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                        |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'just_date' at row 1 |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
rj$
```

Comment: Even in the CLI tool, when you tell it to `SHOW WARNINGS`, there's no way to direct the output to a file interactively.  The only way you could do it is if you know _IN ADVANCE_ that you will get errors that you want to capture that you can direct _ALL_ output to a file.  But that also means you can't do anything interactively (it all has to be written in an SQL script) and you can't see what's happening while the script is executing.

Comment: @Big_Al_Tx - OK, you forced me to figure out the details.  See my edit.

Comment: Ok, this _will_ allow me to capture warnings in an external file, but only if I'm using the CLI tool. But I'm wondering if HeidiSQL would recognize the `tee` command ... I'll have to check that.  I do have to admit that I misunderstood how to invoke the `tee` command; I thought it had to be used within the SQL statement.  Thanks for that.

Comment: From the CLI, type `help`; you will get a bunch of commands that talk to the CLI, not the server.  `tee` is one of them.  And, since `tee` does not talk to the server, it won't lose the `WARNINGs`.

Comment: `<rant>`So, is HeidiSQL a 3rd-party package that gets in the way of using MySQL?`</rant>`

Comment: I just tried it, and HeidiSQL doesn't seem to recognize the `tee` command.  If I were to guess (and based on the error message I got), I think it's just doing straight SQL syntax checking and not accounting for other MySQL/MariaDB commands. I wouldn't say it's getting in the way -- it's just that it doesn't support the full range of allowable commands. It's too bad, because it's actually a pretty good GUI tool. And switching to MySQL Workbench is a sketchy proposition because it complains about incompatibilities (possibly to discourage MariaDB users).  Thanks again.